# How to get coupon times used with coupon code using REST Api?

Tags: magento2, coupon, coupon-codes, magento-2.1.2, rest-api

I have no experience with Magento. I was asigned the task to validate a coupon code via magento rest api. I've tried to use `/V1/coupons/search` GET method. My request url is:

```
 https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/coupons/search/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=code&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=12345ABC&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

However, my java based server receives a 500 status response.

I've also tried to make a curl request like this:

> curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer some-token-string"

```
https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/coupons/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=code&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=1234ABC&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq"
```

However my console responds:

```
curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 92
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @alex-g, what version of magento are you using?

Comment: 2.1.2 . Sorry, should have included it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the *--globoff* argument to your curl command. Curl's globbing feature is misinterpreting the braces in Magento's query syntax as a request for curl to make multiple requests based on a range.

E.g.

```
curl -X GET --globoff --header "Authorization: Bearer some-token-string" https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/coupons/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=code&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=1234ABC&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq"
```

Documentation for the feature is available here:

https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline-globbing.html

Comment: Link redirects to here now: https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/globbing

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2x: vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/etc/webapi.xml

Check all coupon related APi End Point

```
<!-- Coupon CRUD -->
    <route url="/V1/coupons/:couponId" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_SalesRule::quote"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/coupons/search" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_SalesRule::quote"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/coupons" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_SalesRule::quote"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/coupons/:couponId" method="PUT">
        <service class="Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_SalesRule::quote"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/coupons/:couponId" method="DELETE">
        <service class="Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponRepositoryInterface" method="deleteById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_SalesRule::quote"/>
        </resources>
    </route>

    <!-- Coupon Management -->
    <route url="/V1/coupons/generate" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponManagementInterface" method="generate"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_SalesRule::quote"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/coupons/deleteByIds" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponManagementInterface" method="deleteByIds"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_SalesRule::quote"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/coupons/deleteByCodes" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponManagementInterface" method="deleteByCodes"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_SalesRule::quote"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```